# WPF Webbrowser navigate to byte[] while still loading images

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF application that has a dynamic view that shows images, PDFs, or HTML web pages. My application hits a web service to request these types of files and then based on the mime type returned, chooses an image control, a pdf control, or the WPF WebBrowser control to render the returned data.

With Images and PDFs, I can check the mime type and then immediately pass the byte array from the result to the control for rendering.

However, if the mime type is HTML, then the only way I have found to render the html is to give the URL to the web browser control's Navigate function which results in a second HTTP call to the remote service.  I have been asked to remove this second request if possible.

I have tried passing the byte array (e.Result) to the browser control as a stream, however, the browser has no url to reference and therefore can't resolve relatively linked resources like images. Is there any way that I can pass the byte array to the web browser where it will still know how to make the requests for relatively linked content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that out of the box, because of how WPF (and WinForms) browsers are implemented. When loading from stream or string, they will always have url of "about:blank". Options to achieve your goal which come to my mind:

1. Modify html you downloaded by adding

```html
<base href="http://your_site.com" />
```

tag inside head element (or create head if not present):

```
string html;
string url = "http://google.com";
var r = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
using (var rs = r.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()) {
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(rs, Encoding.UTF8)) {
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
 }
 // god forbid to do it like this, example only!
 html = html.Replace("<head>", "<head><base href=\"" + url + "\"");
 wb.NavigateToString(html);
```

2. Use non-standard browser. I use CEF (chromium embedded) browser for all my wpf projects, because default WPF browser does not satisfy my needs in many aspects. C# binding for CEF - https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp (there are others too).